# How can we say that Helium (He) is liquid at "absolute zero"?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, temperature

According to Wikipedia, Helium can never be solidified at $\pu{1 atm}$ ($\pu{101325 Pa}$) pressure, not even at absolute zero. A minimum of $\pu{25 atm}$ pressure is required to make Helium solid. But absolute zero ($\pu{0 K}$) is not attainable, how can we say that Helium is liquid at absolute zero with $\pu{1 atm}$ pressure? It can never be proved. Is it a theory?

Comment: This is an extrapolation, based on our understanding of its nature.

Comment: It is similar as if mathemations say $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\frac {\sin x}{x}\right)}=1$$

Comment: Because the zero-point energy exceeds binding forces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy *Are you certain about that position, Herr Heisenberg?*